# Mixed Write for GSON

Tags: jmeter, gson

I am using GSON object model access to construct JSON to be used as body of my POST webservice calls in Jmeter.

Now I frequently encounter : GCC Out of memory exception with the error pointing to the code section=> gson.toJson(objectToSerialize).
From the past posts, it was suggested to use gson serialization with the streaming access model.

My current code does this: Create an object of an class by populating its variables and passes this class on to the GSON serializer, gets back the constructed JSON in form of string and I use them.

Could the experts suggest, is there a way that I could integrate streaming access model into my code without having to do much of a rework. Would this be memory efficient?
PS: I took a look into Mixed writes example specified in this link but unable to get around how to construct a JSON by passing one object of the class as we do in the object model:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use these variables in "Body Data" mode of the HTTP Request sampler like:

[image: JSON Send Example]

If your JSON payload is large you may have to amend Java HEAP size as default allocation is just 512MB and it may be not enough for more or less large load. If you don't have enough free RAM to fit JSON data size * number of virtual users you may have to consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

The other option may be you using not very efficient scripting test element. It is recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and Groovy as a language as other options are not performing that well.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for more information on

Comment: Thanks Dmriti. I was facing memory issues which I overcame by increasing heap size.However I see that the above method of constructing a large JSON,drives the memory close to about 97% and looking for a way to construct it in a memory efficient way and seeking the best way to do it.